# CSS shaking gif with transition

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transitions

I have a problem with a project i'm working on,
when I hover my div's cards, I change the background image from jpg to a gif and resize it thanks to flexbox grow.

However during the transition the image of the GIF seems to be shaking or trembling.
I've tried to change the margins to translate, as well as few code found on stack overflow which unfortunatly didn't do the trick for me :

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container-general {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width 100%;
}

.containing-cards {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 600px;
  width: 1500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.pillone {
  width: 8%;
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 1%;
  transition: all 1600ms ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* CODE FOUND ON STACK OVERFLOW, DOESNT WORK FOR ME*/
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
}

#map {
  transform: translate(0%, 3%);
}

#general,
#notif {
  transform: translate(0%, -3%);
}

#usage,
#history {
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  ;
}

#general {
  background-image: url('https://iili.io/2kw2Fn.jpg');
}

#general:hover {
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/68MVb2c/data-gif.gif');
}

#usage {
  background-image: url('https://iili.io/2khoOl.jpg');
}

#usage:hover {
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/rwcxwtN/usage-gif.gif');
}

#map {
  background-image: url('https://iili.io/2ksJPs.jpg');
}

#general,
#usage,
#map {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

#general:hover,
#usage:hover,
#map:hover {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.pillone:hover {
  flex-grow: 2;
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1800px) {
  .containing-cards {
    height: 300px;
    width: 750px;
  }
  .pillone {
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .containing-cards {
    height: 150px;
    width: 375px;
  }
  .pillone {
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .containing-cards {
    height: 75px;
    width: 187.5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-general">
    <div class="containing-cards">
      <div class="pillone" id="general"></div>
      <div class="pillone" id="usage"></div>
      <div class="pillone" id="map"></div>
      <div class="pillone" id="history"></div>
      <div class="pillone" id="notif"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I can't understand what shaking you got, it looks good in the snippet, isn't it?

Comment: Hi :) unfortunately not in full screen. Try to open the snippet in full page

Comment: The shaking isn't very big but still bothering, especially if you hover for the first time

Comment: Sorry, I still can't see it.
When I open it and hover a picture, it expands and transferred to gif and there is a little "jump" at the end of the expansion but no shaking.

Comment: well the bug looks like it dissapeared by itself... i'll leave this question opened in case it comes back, otherwise i will delete it in few days